# Image not appearing clear on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an image (512 x 512 pixels 299.98 pixels/inch). The code I am using to display the image in button is

```
UIImage *cameraImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[cameraButton setImage:cameraImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if(IS_IPAD)
    cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.04,self.view.frame.size.height*0.75,cameraImage.size.width*0.5,cameraImage.size.height*0.5);
else
    cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*0.04,self.view.frame.size.height*0.75,cameraImage.size.width*0.25,cameraImage.size.width*0.25);
```

Now the image displays great on iPad (Both Retina and normal), iPhone Retina. But the image shows very clumsy on iPhone 3GS. Look at the screenshot attached.

Please help me find out what is going wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, that's how interpolating images works. You should make a version for non-retina devices of the image.

Comment: So how I create the non-retina version ? Do I create an image with half the pixel ? Do I need to set any fixed DPI ?

Comment: @userXXX Use some image manipulation program (Photoshop, GIMP, ...) to create an image which is half as wide and tall as the original.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. Is there any tool which can take a big image and generate all the assets ?

Comment: @userXXX I don't know of one. At our company, the graphics designer guy exported all images in 2 resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by iOS' graphics frameworks' behavior - they interpolate the image, which introduces loss in quality. You need to generate a smaller image (of half of the resolution of the original one) and include that in your project as well.